# Cosmos DB apply changes to existing data

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I'm using Cosmos DB in an attempt to keep a Web App as cheap / free as possible. I'm not very familiar with it.
I've added a bunch of data. Approx 200 rows in a table called Members. I then added more fields. In particular this field

```
public bool ArchiveMember { get; set; }
```

Any new Members I add have the ArchiveMember field, but existing data doesn't include the new field (set as false) as I expected.
Is there a way of applying migrations to all data?

Comment: You should update the data yourself using a script or tool. It might be simpler to have the entity have a default value for the `ArchiveMember` property instead of updating all data.
You could also take a look at [Table Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/tables/table-storage-overview) which is a feature of Storage Accounts. The API is also supported by Cosmos DB, enabling you to start with a storage account and migrate over if requirements or performance change.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you [rickvdbosch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1945525/rickvdbosch) ,Posting your comment as an answer to help other community members for this similar issue.

"You should update the data yourself using a script or tool. It might be simpler to have the entity have a default value for the `ArchiveMember` property instead of updating all data. You could also take a look at [Table Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/tables/table-storage-overview) which is a feature of Storage Accounts. The API is also supported by Cosmos DB, enabling you to start with a storage account and migrate over if requirements or performance change."